# Can you apply a function to parameter before its parent function is called?

Tags: javascript

Here is a watered down example of the original source:

**Snippet 1**

```
function slice(obj) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(obj,0);
}

function logEach(a) {
    a = slice(a);

    a.forEach(function(o) {
        console.log(o.nodeType);
    });
}

logEach(document.getElementsByTagName('*'));
```

I'm wondering if there's some way to apply a function to parameter 'a' before the function is called, for example:

**Snippet 2**

```
//doesn't work

function logEach(a = slice(a)) {
    a.forEach( //... etc.
```

I know the following is possible, but I'm curious to know if there is a way to implement that previous snippet (*snippet 2*):

**Snippet 3**

```
//works
function slice(obj) {
    // ... etc.
}

function logEach(a) {
    a.forEach( // ... etc.

// then later on...

logEach(slice(document.getElementsByTagName('*')));
```

Is it possible to avoid *snippet 3*, and do something similar to *snippet 2*?
Also, would the attempt made in *snippet 2* be referred to as parameter mapping?

**Edit**

Thanks p.s.w.g. for prompting me to clarify this:

In my case, I will be using 'a' more than once, so I wouldn't want to use `slice(a).forEach`

Comment: I've never seen anything like snippet 2 in javascript. In PHP, as you may know, '=' gives a default value, but you can't use complex expressions with those. Anyway, could the Proxy Pattern meet your needs?

Comment: **Snippet 4**: `slice(a).forEach(function(o) ...)`

Comment: You can't execute operation like this in parameter definition in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you only use the result of `slice(a)` once in your method body (in `a.forEach`) you could just as easily write it like this:

```
function logEach(a) {
    slice(a).forEach(function(o) {
        console.log(o.nodeType);
    });
}
```

However, if you have to refer to it many times there are three options, as far as I can see. The easy way which you're already using:

```
function logEach(a) {
    a = slice(a);
    a.forEach(function(o) {
        console.log(o.nodeType);
    });
}
```

By wrapping the content of the function like this:

```
function logEach(a) {
    (function(a) {
        a.forEach(function(o) {
            console.log(o.nodeType);
        });
    })(slice(a));
}
```

By wrapping the entire like this:

```
function logEach(a) {
    a.forEach(function(o) {
        console.log(o.nodeType);
    });
}
logEach = (function(f) { 
    return function(a) { f(slice(a)); }; 
})(logEach);
```

These last two options look clever, but they really just make your code harder to read and don't really provide a whole lot of benefit. I'd recommend just keeping things simple.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  In my case, I will be using 'a' more than once, so I wouldn't want to use slice(a).forEach.  I will edit my question to specify that stipulation. I like the third snippet of the four you provided.  Do you think passing slice(a) as a parameter to the SIAF (as you demonstrated) is much different performance-wise than simply declaring var a = slice(a)?

Comment: @JoshBeam The performance difference probably wouldn't be significant, unless you're calling this *many* times. Note that there is some cost to creating and invoking the function (IIFE) inside the function. The 4th option should have slightly better performance, because it it only creates that inner function once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this is what you are looking for, but you could write something like a function decorator:

```
//decorator logic

function sliceDec(func, args) {
    return func(slice(args[0]));
}

function decorate(func, decorator) {
    return function () {
        return decorator(func, arguments);
    }
}

//original code

function slice(obj) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(obj,0);
}

function logEach(a) {
    a.forEach(function(o) {
        console.log(o.nodeType);
    });
}

//apply decorator

var logEachSliced = decorate(logEach, sliceDec);

//call function

logEachSliced(document.getElementsByTagName('*'));
```

But this just basically wraps your function in another function (and you will find other ways to do that, besides this one), that call `slice` on the first argument, before handling it to the original function.